# How am i able to split elements in a list into their own elements?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a `list` as follows:

```
my_list = ["David Smith", "John Wilson", "Mike Davis", "Shawn Jones", 
            "Shawn Gilmour", "David Berman"]
```

If I want to get a `list` such that the `first` and `last` names are separated so that I can `count` all instances of the `first` names, how can I do so?

Comment: You mean a list of lists like `[["David", "Smith"], ["John", "Wilson"], ...]`? Use a list comprehension that calls `split()`.

Comment: `defaultdict` is advised here

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python split names", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` with a generator expression that extract the first names with `str.split`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(name.split()[0] for name in my_list)
```

This returns:

```
Counter({'David': 2, 'Shawn': 2, 'John': 1, 'Mike': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["David Smith", "John Wilson", "Mike Davis", "Shawn Jones", "Shawn Gilmour", "David Berman"]

new_list = []

for ele in my_list:
    for name in ele.split():
        new_list.append(name)
```

**Output:**

```
print (new_list)
['David', 'Smith', 'John', 'Wilson', 'Mike', 'Davis', 'Shawn', 'Jones', 'Shawn', 'Gilmour', 'David', 'Berman']
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `defaultdict`. Store first names as key to the dict and add 1 per first name.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
my_list = ["David Smith", "John Wilson", "Mike Davis", "Shawn Jones", 
            "Shawn Gilmour", "David Berman"]

for first, last in map(lambda x: x.split(), my_list):
    result[first] += 1

David: 2
John: 1
Mike: 1
Shawn: 2
```

If ever needed, you can use `defaultdict(list)` and append issue `result[first].append(last)` which will give you first name as key and list of last names as its values which could be useful if use case arises.